# C# DateTimeSqlNullValueException: Data is Null

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, null

I start MySQL query going to a list with one value that is a DateTime object.  As this list builds it hits a null value and --- `DateTimeSqlNullValueException: Data is Null`.

First I naively tried using `ISNULL`, `!=NULL`, `==NULL`... which are not methods of the DateTime object.  Then I tried

```
queryResult.EventTime = rdr.GetDateTime("timeIn");

if (Convert.IsDBNull(rdr.GetDateTime("timeIn")))
{
    Console.Write("yeup it's null");
    queryResult2.EventTime = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

This didn't work either.

Then I though instead of `rdr.GetDateTime()` I thought maybe using `GetString()` instead and use the methods for strings to test for null then change it back to a `DateTime` and set it to `DateTime.MinValue`so I could address it in the view later on.  This seemed like a total cludge and not very elegant.  So I have been searching for the one liner that I can test the nullness of `rdr.GetDateTime("timeIn");` and set it to `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which will do the check and so make it a one liner (untested code, but should give you the idea):

```
public static GetDateTimeOrDefault(this IDataReader dr, string columnName, DateTime defaultValue)
{
    int ordinal = dr.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    if (dr.IsDbNull(ordinal))
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return dr.GetDateTime(ordinal);
}
```

you can then call this like so:

```
queryResult.EventTime = rdr.GetDateTimeOrDefault("timeIn",DateTime.MinValue);
```

you don't need to pass in the default value, but its a good idea to do so, as you then have control from the calling site to specify the value you want if the database field is null, and the calling site is where you will know what value you want.  you may not always want `DateTime.MinValue`, you may want `DateTime.Now` sometimes for example

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `GetDateTime` until you *know* the value isn't null:

```
if (rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("timeIn"))))
{
    Console.Write("yeup it's null");
    queryResult2.EventTime = DateTime.MinValue;
}
else
{
    queryResult.EventTime = rdr.GetDateTime("timeIn");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately with (rdr.IsDBNull... the compiler complains: Error the best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.IsDBNull(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @rd42 This is what he meant when he said `It's possible that you'll need to give the column index rather than the name ` see my answer, you need to get the ordinal of the column first.

Comment: Ah, Thanks Sam. So something like if (Convert.IsDBNull(rdr.GetDateTime(5)))  but with the correct syntax

Comment: @rd42 I've updated this answer so it *should* work.  If you want to make this into a one liner at the calling site then try the extension method technique.

Comment: Thanks again Sam.  I tried the update with the same result.  Possibly the column index like you two mentioned.  Is it the columnindex like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or something totally different.

Comment: @rd42 yes you need to provide it with a column index, but this is what  [GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getordinal.aspx) does.  It takes a `string` and returns an `int` so this should be ok.  Are you sure this is the error?

Comment: @rd42: You say you get "the same result" - where *exactly* is the exception being thrown?

Comment: @JonSkeet according to his comment I'm assuming its a compiler error, not an exception.

Comment: @SamHolder: Ah, right - I assumed it was "the same error as he was originally getting"

Comment: @SamHolder and JonSkeet  I really appreciate your help and apologize. Your edit did work, perfectly, I just didn't notice that a little farther down in my script I was trying to use the same value.  Thank you guys again, it's great to have people to work with even though I'm in a tiny cinder block office.(use to be a closet :)

Comment: @rd42 np, glad we could help.  did you try using the extension method?  I've found that in a lot of cases where you need to do something specific on null when reading from the database you can reduce a lot of the boiler plate code to a single line

Comment: I did but didn't get it to work initially, so I went back to the Jon's suggestion and the yours. The extension method the way I would like to do it, cleaner and I could use the extension again.  Thank you again Sam, I will try it.